# Change attribute value to position of another element with corresponding attribute value

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a single XHTML document that contains `span` and `div` elements that refer to page breaks of a print version using `id` and `epub:type` attributes. For example: `<div epub:type="pagebreak" id="page-3"/>`. The document also has links to those elements, for example: `<a href="#page-3">3</a>`.

This single XHTML document will be split into multiple XHTML documents to form an EPUB package. For this reason, the `href` attributes need to be updated to match the new location of the corresponding `id`. For example: `<a href="02.xhtml#page-3">3</a>`. The name of the new XHTML file is equal to the position of the `body/section` elements. So in the last example, the page break with `id="page-3"` is apparently in the second `body/section` element.

I'm using the following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<!--identity transform-->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--variable to match id of elements with pagebreak values-->
<xsl:variable name="page-id" select="//*[@epub:type = 'pagebreak']/@id"/>

<!--update href attributes to match new filenames-->
<xsl:template match="a/@href">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tokenize(., '#')[last()] = $page-id">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:number count="//body/section[$page-id = tokenize(., '#')[last()]]" format="01"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('.xhtml', .)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It checks for `href` attributes that have a corresponding `id` using the `$page-id` variable. If there is a match, the `href` attribute should be updated using the `count()` function. Otherwise, the `href` should remain unchanged. The `test` seems to work, however, I'm not getting the result I want. This is the input:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <p>Link to page 3: <a href="#page-3">3</a></p>
    </section>
    <section>      
        <div epub:type="pagebreak" id="page-3"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

This is the output I get:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <p>Link to page 3: <a href=".xhtml#page-3">3</a></p>
    </section>
    <section>      
        <div epub:type="pagebreak" id="page-3"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

This is the output I want:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <p>Link to page 3: <a href="02.xhtml#page-3">3</a></p>
    </section>
    <section>      
        <div epub:type="pagebreak" id="page-3"/>
    </section>
</body>
```

It seems as if the XPath expression within `xsl:number` doesn't return a result, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="body/section" mode="number">
  <xsl:number format="01"/>
<xsl:template>
```

and then instead of

```
 <xsl:number count="//body/section[$page-id = tokenize(., '#')[last()]]" format="01"/>
```

use

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="key('page-id', substring-after(., '#'))" mode="number"/>
```

plus a key declaration

```
<xsl:key name="page-id" match="body/section" use=".//*[@epub:type = 'pagebreak']/@id"/>
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! I haven't used the mode attribute before, so I'm going to read up on that.